# Problem with adding exercises - "missing \item error"

Tags: environments, exercises

I have the following MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \makeatletter

 \usepackage[dutch]{babel}

 \usepackage{blindtext}

 %Paragraphs get numbered continuously
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}


 %How stuff is displayed EVERYWHERE
 \renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}
 \renewcommand\cftparaaftersnum{.}
 \renewcommand\cftparanumwidth{1em}

 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
 \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}


  %How stuff is displayed in the text
 \titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {Hoofdstuk \thesection:}{0.5em}{}

 \titleformat{\paragraph}[block]
 {\normalfont\bfseries}
 {Paragraaf \theparagraph:}{0.5em}{}


 \newcounter{exercise}[section]
 \newcounter{exercisestar}[section]
 \renewcommand{\theexercise}{\thesection.\@Alph\c@exercise \hspace{6pt}}
 \renewcommand{\theexercisestar}{\thesection.\@Alph\c@exercise*}

 \newcommand{\exercisestarmark}[1]{} 
 \newcommand{\exercisemark}[1]{} 
 \newcommand{\exercise}{\@startsection{exercise}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}

 \newcommand{\exercisestar}{
                                \stepcounter{exercise}
                                \@startsection{exercisestar}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
                                }



 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents


\section{Volledige inductie}

    \paragraph{Inleiding}

    \paragraph{Getalrijen}

    \exercise {}

    Some exercise

    \section{Optelling en vermenigvuldiging}

   \paragraph{Optelling}

   \paragraph{Vermenigvuldiging}

\end{document}
```

The problem is now that when adding exercises, latex does not compile properly. I would be happy if someone could point out why this is or how the code could be improved.

EDIT: I now realized that removing "\tableofcontents" solves the problem ... But I really want to have the table of contents in my notes.

Second Edit: When removing the .toc file, the first time I compile everything works fine. When compiling afterwards, I get the error again. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[dutch]{babel}

 \usepackage{blindtext}

 %Paragraphs get numbered continuously
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}


 %How stuff is displayed EVERYWHERE
 \renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}
 \renewcommand\cftparaaftersnum{.}
 \renewcommand\cftparanumwidth{1em}

 \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
 \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}


  %How stuff is displayed in the text
 \titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {Hoofdstuk \thesection:}{0.5em}{}

 \titleformat{\paragraph}[block]
 {\normalfont\bfseries}
 {Paragraaf \theparagraph:}{0.5em}{}

 \makeatletter
 \newcounter{exercise}[section]
 \renewcommand{\theexercise}{\thesection.\@Alph\c@exercise\hspace{6pt}}

 \newcommand{\exercisemark}[1]{} 
 \newcommand{\exercise}{\@startsection{exercise}{2}{\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
   {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}}

 \newcommand{\fakercise}[1]% #1 = title
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}%
   \exercise*{\theexercise\hspace{1em}#1}}

\newcommand*{\l@exercise}{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents


\section{Volledige inductie}

    \paragraph{Inleiding}

    \paragraph{Getalrijen}

    \exercise{title}

    some exercise

    \fakercise{title}

    some exercise

    \section{Optelling en vermenigvuldiging}

   \paragraph{Optelling}

   \paragraph{Vermenigvuldiging}

\end{document}
```

[image: cropped page]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What, if I do not want to display the exercises in the table of contents ?

Comment: \exercise* is already defined, but it doesn't do what you want.  I can create a fake section heading, but I don't know how to turn off indentation for the next paragraph (only).

Comment: Aha!  You can USE \exercise* in another macro to achieve what you want.  It's a matter of parameter passing.